# Unable to assign a drive letter to my Ubuntu partition from Windows

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, disk-management

I recently reinstalled Windows 7 and backed up my files on my Ubuntu partition. Now I would like to retrieve them, but the Ubuntu partition isn't visible from my file browser. My research revealed that I needed to assign a drive letter in Disk Management. Unfortunately that option is grayed out (so everything else except for "Delete Volume"). Does anyone know why it would be grayed out or a solution besides the one I found? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's grayed out because Windows does not support any of the filesystems that Linux uses, therefore the only thing it *can* do to that partition is to delete it.

If your Ubuntu partition uses the ext4 filesystem (the most popular one), you may try [Ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/), although personally I only trust it for read-only access.

Ubuntu, however, can access Windows partitions (the `ntfs-3g` driver provides support for the NTFS filesystem), so you could reboot into Ubuntu and copy files from it.